# Can't pass parameters to JAR file from Powershell... works in command prompt

Tags: java, powershell, jar, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

When I try to run the following in Powershell

```
& java -jar myEncrypter.jar abc123
```

I get the error:

> SEVERE: null java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size

However, if I run this in a command prompt, it works

```
java -jar myEncrypter.jar abc123
```

Note: The path to Java, C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin, is setup correctly, so that is not the problem.

Comment: What does `(Get-Command java).Path` return?

Comment: C:\Windows\system32\java.exe

Comment: So that's not the same as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin'.  Try executing `& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java" -jar myEncrypter.jar abc123`.

Answer (score 3):

You're not running the same java exe between the two environments.  Not sure why the Path is different between cmd.exe and PowerShell but it apparently is.  Use a full path to java.exe or fix the path that PowerShell sees.

Answer (score 0):

Keith Hill was correct... I needed to reference C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin in both the path to the jar and the path to java.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java -jar C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\myEncrypter.jar abc123
```